# Contact Form 7 in tabs adds to url and redirects but doesn't submit

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4, contact-form-7

I have a contact form 7 form that is inside a bootstrap tab.  When submitted it adds to the url the form submission but doesn't actually submit the form.

I'm guessing it is something to do with form handlers but i'm not sure.  The code below is loading the page to the same tab when reloading so that part is done.  I just can't get the form to submit.

```
$('.nav-item a').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).tab('show');
});


$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
window.location.hash = id;
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
$('.nav-item a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

And the code below is the HTML for the form

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="contact_d-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact_d" role="tab" aria-controls="contact_d" aria-selected="true">Contact Details</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="form-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#form" role="tab" aria-controls="form" aria-selected="false">Contact Form</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contact_d" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact_d-tab">
        <div class="contact_info">
          <h3>
            Contact Information
          </h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>&nbsp;<span>Council Clerk</span> - <?php the_field('clerk_name'); ?>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>&nbsp;<?php the_field('address', 'options'); ?>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;<a href="tel:<?php the_field('phone', 'options'); ?>"><?php the_field('phone', 'options'); ?></a><br>
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:<?php the_field('email', 'options'); ?>"><?php the_field('email', 'options'); ?></a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <p class="info">You may contact any Colwall Parish Councillor by e-mailing the Clerk, who will forward any correspondence. Alternatively, all Councillor's details can be found below.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="form" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="form-tab">
        <form>
          <h3>
            Contact Form
          </h3>
          <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="618" title="Contact form"]'); ?>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Thankyou for your help in advance.

Comment: You're not submitting the form in JS.  What gets echo'd to the DOM for your form?

Comment: $('#formID').submit();

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/submit/